# How to use PAPI with C++11 std:thread?

Tags: c++11, profiling, stdthread, papi

I would like to use PAPI to get the overall counters of all C++11 `std::thread`  threads in a program.

[PAPI documentation on Threads](https://icl.cs.utk.edu/projects/papi/wiki/Threads) says that:

> Thread support in the PAPI library can be initialized by calling the following low-level function in C: `int PAPI_thread_init(unsigned long(*handle)(void));`

where the handle is a

> Pointer to a routine that returns the current thread ID as an unsigned long.

For example, for pthreads the handle is `pthread_self`.
But, I have no idea what it should be with C++11 `std::thread`.
Nor if it makes more sense to use something different from PAPI.

Comment: Check e.g. [this `std::thread` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread). I'm sure you can find some member function that can help you.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/native_handle

Answer (score 0):

C++11 threading support has the [std::this_thread::get_id()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/get_id) function that returns a [std::thread::id](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/id) instance which can be serialized to a stream. Then you coud try to read an `unsigned long` from the stream and return ir. Something like this:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

unsigned long current_thread_id()
{
    std::stringstream id_stream;
    id_stream << std::this_thread::get_id();
    unsigned long id;
    id_stream >> id;
    return id;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::cout << current_thread_id();
    return 0;
}
```

So in this snippet the `current_thread_id` function is what you are looking for, but you should add proper error handling (the thread id may not always be a number, in that case you will not be able to read a number from the stream and you should handle that accordingly).

That being said, maybe just use [GetCurrentThreadId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683183(v=vs.85).aspx) , since you are already introducing the Linux specific `pthread_self`.

Comment: I tried what you suggest here but I guess it does not work. 
The counters didn't change and I'm far away from the values I get with `perf` on some same counters.

Comment: @nicolacdnll what counters are we talking about? :) the question did not mention anything about that. Did you check if the function is being called and what is the return value?

Comment: Right now I'm interested on level 3 total cache accesses and level 1, 2 and 3 total cache hits but later on I might want to look into other stuff. The `current_thread_id` function is called and it returns values like 140318347351808, 140318338959104, et cetera.